# How is the ArcMap Table of Contents mode stored?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

The ArcMap table of Contents has several display modes - List By Drawing Order; List By Source etc (described [here](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-arcmap/using-the-table-of-contents.htm)).

[image]

How or where this is saved? Is it saved within the MXD file or is there a system setting somewhere that controls it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking about is called the "Last Tab Index", and it is a user-based setting stored in the registry and not in any MXDs.  For ArcGIS 10.8.x, the registry setting is:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\ESRI\Desktop10.8\ArcMap\TOC\Views]
"Last Tab Index"=dword:00000000
```

The corresponding index values are:

```
0 = List By Drawing Order
1 = List By Source
2 = List By Visibility
3 = List By Selection
```

Any value besides one of those four will be changed at start-up back to `0` - List By Drawing Order.

Answer (score 1):

They are just buttons that alter the view of the TOC. The status will be recorded within the MXD. You would need to use ArcObjects to interact with it in a programmatic way.

Here is the VBA you could run within the mxd that would return the actively selected button:

```vb
Public Sub Test()
    Dim pMXD As IMxDocument
    Set pMXD = ThisDocument
    Dim pCV As IContentsView3
    Set pCV = pMXD.CurrentContentsView
    Debug.Print pCV.Name
End Sub
```